# How to install Oracle 11gR2 Enterprise Edition on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: oracle

I couldn't find any tutorial to install  Oracle 11gR2 Enterprise Edition on Ubuntu 16.10? Please help.

Comment: @Thomas , the process is same for ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: I need Enterprise edition and the answer is for Express edition

Comment: @ElderGeek link you mentioned is for Oracle linux platform... we are asking for Ubuntu